# How to handle special character in Kotlin Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a String which I am getting from API (no control over it). When the String contains a special character like an apostrophe, it will be converted to something else.

It looks something like this:

```
text_view.text = "Hannah's Law"
```

When displayed on Android, it will be:

```
Hannah&#39;s Law
```

I tried to convert the String to byteArray and then encode to UTF-8 but no luck:

```
val byteArray = template.execute(bindingDictionary).toByteArray() // This is the Actual String
String(byteArray,Charsets.UTF_8) // Did not work
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
&#39;
```

is HTML for the apostrophe. You can use fromHtml to convert that to text with the apostrophe.

```
    val fromApi = "Hannah&#39;s Law"
    val textFromHtmlFromApi = HtmlCompat.fromHtml(fromApi, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
    text_view.text = textFromHtmlFromApi
```

Answer (score 1):

use unicode symbols like here https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/unicode-characters.html
for example instead

```
String str = "Hannah's Law"
```

use

```
String str = "Hannah\u0027s Law"
```

same thing if you need for example space in the end of string

```
String str = "string with space in the end\u0020"
```

for Kotlin use

```
var str: String = "string with space in the end\u0020"
```